# Sum up the following series: $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find an explicit formula for the term
$$\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{2^k}$$
Then I discovered that
$$\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k^2}{2^k}=1^22^n+2^22^{n-1}+3^22^{n-2}+\cdots+n^22^1-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
But how to write $1^22^n+2^22^{n-1}+3^22^{n-2}+\cdots+n^22^1$ into explicit formula??
$$\\$$ A hint would be grateful.

---

Comment: Hint: Differentiate once and twice the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$$

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/828705/5531) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172140/5531).